# Best way to display animated image (HTML/CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, animation

On my website I'm trying to display the animation of a coin being flipped multiple times in the air and coming back to the surface. When the animation is over it should become a static image of the side the coin landed on. 
I've found multiple ways to do this such as CSS animations, sprites,... but the options with CSS animations seem to be very limited if I want a rather advanced animation and others seem to have some flaws aswell. 
What is the best method of displaying an animated image for a certain amount of time and then becoming a static image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use Javascript.  You could do:

```
<img src="animation.gif" alt="coin" id="yourImage">

<script>
    var image = document.getElementById('yourImage');
    window.setTimeout(changeImage, millisecondsToEndOfAnimation);
    function changeImage() {
        image.src = "staticImage.png";
    }
</script>
```